# Words Not Auto Capitalizing in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I have a search bar and I am trying to have words auto capitalize, like this:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
    searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
}
```

The shift key is highlighted by default when the keyboard comes up but it doesn't capitalize any words automatically.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the delegate set? If not, set it. Are you testing in the Simulator and using your hardware keyboard? If yes, try using the Simulator's own keyboard or test in your device.

Comment: The delegate is set and the search bar works like I want it to other than this. And, yes, I am testing in the simulator and using my hardware keyboard to type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Capitalization is ignored when you use your hardware keyboard while testing with the simulator. Try in a device or use the Simulator's keyboard.